# How to set Focus in Unbounded datagridview specified columns?

Tags: c#, .net

In My Project I'm Using a Unbounded Datagridview With specified Columns like ID, Item Name, Item Code, Size, Color, Rate, Quantity, Total. Here i made my End User to Enter the Item Name / Item-code and Quantity only. Remaining Columns Will Be auto Completed. Now My Problem is When End User Enter the Item Name/ Item Code the Focus Should set to the quantity and when quantity as enter then the focus should be in new row on Item Name/ Item Code .

is it possible . can anybody give me a right it to achieve this task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using c# and the DataGridView you can set the focus by using the following example:

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1[columnnumber,rownumber];

To put it in edit mode: 
DataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

Hope this helps.